# webpack multicompile via node api (^4.44.2)

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a Webpack configuration repository to separate the `application boilerplate` from the `Webpack configuration`. This application is dependent on the repository where the Webpack configuration is. I made a binary in the Webpack repository so that, in the application, I could compile and run this configuration in development. The configuration combines a common configuration with the past environment.

Problem: The scenario is beautiful but it is not working in the part of compiling and serving the application. Apparently my configuration is OK - i isolate them and test them separately. And I'm also following the v4 documentation for NODE-API.

As I have nowhere to turn, I'm sorry if I'm not on the right platform, i am studying how to compile different configurations of the same application (boilerplate) using webpack.

[Link to the code.](https://pastebin.com/Uqu90bdy)

i appreciate some repo example...

Answer (score 0):

I came across several problems pointing to the Libs of the Webpack and Webpack-dev-server packages. However, today I got what I wanted. I will share here for future reference from other users.

My goal was to be able to trigger the development or production environment from a node script. Involving the construction of multiple FrontEnd applications, which was abstracted in `webpack.config`.

Now i can run `mycli development` on shell and this will trigger the construction of the configuration for that environment.

```js
// mycli.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const webpack = require('webpack')
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
const webpackConfiguration = require('./webpack/webpack.config')
const args = (process.argv && process.argv.length > 2) ? process.argv.slice(2) : []
const mode = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : 'development'
const config = webpackConfiguration(mode)

/**
 * Minimum webpack configuration for cli validation.
 * @see {@link webpackConfiguration} to further information
 */
const minConfig = {
  entry: __dirname + '/test.js',
  mode,
  output: {
    path: '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}

/** @type {WebpackCompilerInstance} compiler */
const compiler = webpack(minConfig)
switch (config.mode) {
  case 'development':
    /**
     * Recommended by documentation:
     *    "If you're using dev-server through the Node.js API,
     *    the options in devServer will be ignored. Pass the options
     *    as a second parameter instead."
     * @see {@link https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver} for further information.
     * @see {@link https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/api/simple} for example
     */
    const devServerConfig = config.devserver;
    if (config) delete config.devserver
    const devServerOptions = Object.assign({}, devServerConfig, {
      open: true,
      stats: {
        colors: true,
      },
    })
    const devserverCallback = (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('webpack-dev-server listening...')
    }
    new WebpackDevServer(compiler, devServerOptions).listen(devServerConfig.port, devServerConfig.host, devserverCallback)
    break;


  case 'production':
    const compilerCallback = (err, stats) => {
      console.log(stats, err)
      if (err) throw err
      process.stdout.write(`Stats: \n${stats} \n`)
      console.log('Compiler has finished execution.')
    }
    compiler.run(compilerCallback)
    break;

  default:
    console.error('No matching mode. Try "development" or "production".')
    break;
}
```